# Windows Server Backup - Can I restore to a particular revision?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup, windows-server-backup

I'm using Windows Server Backup in Windows Server 2008 to do a scheduled daily backup to a dedicated hard-drive on the server.

I noticed that under "All backups" it says I have 45 copies.

Does this mean that I can restore to any revision of my data upon system failure?

If the answer is yes, then I don't have to worry about taking monthly or weekly snapshots of my data. I'm concerned about a data corruption event occurring that working its way into my backups... then not having a clean snapshot to go back to.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be more concerned about relying on temporary media like a hard drive. Not only are hard drives the most unreliable part of a computer but a simple power spike, say from a defective power supply, could take out the whole lot in a millisecond. You should reconsider your backup strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can restore to any of the 45 versions that you have.  This includes a single file, group of files, folder, group of folders or a full blown system restore if you are doing that in your backup sets and really want to.

You also can restore to an alternate location (i.e. not overwrite what is currently there).

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy your backup folder to a external medium

The WindowsImageBackup directory (which is created at the root of the backup target volume), is portable. Please copy the entire WindowsImageBackup directory from the root of the current backup target volume to the other USB storage's volume root. Copying sub-directories of WindowsImageBackup or copying to a folder would not work. After copying, check whether the backup is being listed by using the following command.

wbadmin get versions -backuptarget:g: (where G: is the new USB's volume's drive letter)

Do note since the backup versions on the older USB were stored as shadow copies, only the latest backup can ported using the copy procedure. The moved backup would be good for the Bare Metal Restore and other recoveries. Permissions and reliability of the backup should be intact, just ensure the backup is getting listed using the command above after the copy.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsbackup/thread/23df889b-33b7-4e57-93e1-fee0ace9139f